# Quartz Scheduler firing cron job on all nodes in clustered mode

Tags: java, cron, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I have an application that uses Quartz as a job scheduler. There are two scenarios

1. Schedule a job to execute in the future.
2. A cron job that runs once every 10 seconds.

I run two instances of my application. Both are set to clustered mode and both have instanceId set to "AUTO."

These are my observations:

1. Both instances of the application boots up and connects to the db. Both report that they are clustered and connected to the db successfully.
2. When I schedule a job based on scenario 1, at the time of job execution only a single application executes the job.
3. Scenario 2, i.e. the cron job that executes every 10 seconds, is being executed by both applications at the same time.
4. I look at the qrtz tables in the db. There is only one job and one trigger for the cron job.
5. I also observe in the qrtz db "scheduled state" table that both instances of the application are consistently checking in.

Here is how I setup the cron job:

```
        val myCronJob = newJob(MyCronJob::class.java)
            .withIdentity("cronjob", "cronJobGroup")
            .build()

        val trigger = newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("cronjob", "cronJobGroup")
            .startNow()
            .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires()
                .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
                .repeatForever())
            .build()
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your code snippet  is too small to help. Please provide reproducible working example

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use the @DisallowConcurrentExecution annotation on your job class.

From documentation: 
An annotation that marks a Job class as one that must not have multiple
 * instances executed concurrently (where instance is based-upon a JobDetail
 * definition - or in other words based upon a JobKey).

Answer (score -1):

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true

ensures proper row locks are applied to the trigger before picking it, if that property was false both instances can pick up one trigger.

http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.8.6/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html